# Puppet dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puppet

I'm misunderstanding something about puppet, but I'm having trouble formulating it well enough to succeed at searching for it.

I have some hosts that run rails.  So I have a puppet module that sets up such hosts.

```
class rails_server {
  ...
}
```

And I have some hosts that know how to deploy to rails servers, do tests on rails services, etc.

```
class rails_deployment {
  ...
}
```

And both of them depend on having certain gems installed, a certain ruby version,etc.

```
class rails_dependencies {
  class { '::rvm': }
  rvm_system_ruby { ... }
  rvm_gem { ... }
}
```

But this seems a bit of kludge, because in my `site.pp`, I have to state explicitly that I want `rails_dependencies` installed.  But if instead I have `rails_server` and `rails_deployment` both include `rails_dependencies`, and then try to bring up a test host that can run the server and test and deploy to itself, I get a duplicate declaration error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer the question without more example code. Using `include` will prevent duplicate declarations of the same class, so it's probably somewhere else?

Pasting the error and the lines of code it refers to would be helpful

Comment: Aha, this is it.  If I make the `rails_dependency` a proper module, then the include does, indeed, avoid pulling it in twice.  If I include the _contents_ of that dependency in two different modules that I actually need, then I get the duplicate declaration error on `class { '::rvm': }`.